# Reportlab: dynamic color for table column (color stored in django model) in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I have django model called TestResults

### models.py

```
Class TestResults(models)

   chemical_name charfield
   value    floatfield
   unit  charfield
   method  charfield
   normal_limit charfield
   caution_limit charfield
   color charfield
```

Now,

The below code will generate the table for oils, which has following fields.

### views.py

```
 fields = ('Test Name', 'Value', 'Unit', 'Method',
           'Normal Limit', 'Caution Limit')
 all_oils = [(test.chemical_name, test.value, test.unit, test.method,
                 test.normal_limit, test.caution_limit)
                 for test in TestResult.objects.all())]
oil_table = Table([fields] + all_oils
oil_table.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), '#a7a5a5'),
                              ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 6),
                              ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2, '#a7a5a5'),
                              ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8),
                              ('FONTNAME',(1,1),(1,-1),'Times-Bold')]))
```

Now how can I provide dynamic color for each column. Suppose my TestResult model is having field for color (I,e color=red)

In report i want dynamic color for second column which comes from model objects

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you try formatting the code so it would be more visible? Put 4 spaces before each code line to get it in a code block, then remove all the empty lines in between.

Comment: shahbaz i formatted the code can you help me now?

Comment: Sorry I actually don't know python, I just told you how to make your question look better so that you attract more people.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems really easy.

In your objects, store the color you want in a variable like `color` as a valid ReportLab color specification (e.g. string of hex color value).  Then when you build your report, if you want to set the background color, just set it for all the cells in the column.  For example, to set the background of column `x`, add the following to your `TableStyle`:

```
('BACKGROUND', (x, 0), (x, -1), anObject.color)
```

You can put in as many `'BACKGROUND'` styles as you want in a `TableStyle`, so you can do this for each column you want to change the color of.

Comment: I note that you must import TableStyle:
```from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle```